# problem with NSmutableArray

Tags: memory-leaks, uiview, memory-management, nsmutablearray

```
    - (void)createTileOnScreen:(CGRect)rect
    {
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CGRect bounds = rect;
    CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x,bounds.origin.y, 
            (int)(bounds.size.width / 11), 
            (int)(bounds.size.height / 10)); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
            int index = 10 * i + j;

            Liv *myTile  = [[Liv alloc] initWithFrame:myRect withIndex:index]; 

            float width = (1.0 / 11);
            float height = (1.0 / 10);

                [myTile setImageSection:CGRectMake((j / 11), 
                    (1.0 - ((i+1) / 10)), 
                    width, 
                    height)];
            [self.rotationView addSubview:myTile];
            [myArray addObject:myTile];
            [myTile release];
            myRect.origin.x += myRect.size.width;
        }

        myRect.origin.x = bounds.origin.x;
        myRect.origin.y = myRect.origin.y + myRect.size.height ;



    }
}





    #import "Liv.h"


    @implementation Liv
    @synthesize index;

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withIndex:(int)index_ {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.index = index_;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        fadingAnimationDuration = 2.0;
    }
    return self;
    }

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withIndex:(int)index_ WithColor:(UIColor *)aColor {

    if (self = [self initWithFrame:frame withIndex:index_]) {
        self.backgroundColor = aColor;

    }
     return self;
    }
```

when create tile on screen is called a few times, I see that the allocations keep increasing. Can you please let me know how to deallocate 
myArray without any leaks and also remove it from super view.

Answer (score 2):

Move

```
 myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Out of

```
- (void)createTileOnScreen:(CGRect)rect


[myArray release];
```

Will release your tiles fine. But you might want to iterate through the array prior to release and

```
 [[myArray objectAtIndex:index] removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

How is myArray defined? Is it an instance variable with @propoerty and @synthesize corresponding to it?

it should be

```
self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

with a corresponding

```
@property(retain) myArray;
```

in the .h file. Then you will be ok. As per what you have now, every time the

```
- (void)createTileOnScreen:(CGRect)rect
```

is called, the old NSMutableArray held by myArray leaks when it is replaced by a new NSMutableArray assigned to myArray.